# prevent users from typing on html 5 textboxes

Tags: asp.net, html, textbox

I have two textboxes

a date textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateofAcci" runat="server" BorderColor="#C2C4CC" BorderStyle="Solid" Height="28px" Width="135px" TextMode="Date" BackColor="#F9E3CB"></asp:TextBox>
```

which I have removed the spin button and set a maximum date to prevent users inputing future dates from today, however the users can still type anydate on the field

and next is a number textbox

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAffidAge" runat="server" placeholder="Your Age." type="number" min="18" max="80" value="18"></asp:TextBox>
```

which I have set the minimum to 18 and maximum age to 80
however the users can still type any age on the field.

How can I prevent users from putting their own input on the textbox, and force them to use only the spin button for the number field and the arrow for the calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
onkeydown="return false" onpaste="return false"
```

to the markup of your textboxes. First will block typing in text, second - pasting it.